# How to set position columns Grid by alphabetic Label order in Form?

Tags: forms, label, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

how to set position columns in form dynamics ax by alphabetic Label order ?

I have a Grid in my Form, I want to set the colums position Grid , I think to set this with code x++ in Form Init method, but I don't know how to do.

Thanks for help,

enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add fields manually with the [`addDataField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formbuildgridcontrol.adddatafield(AX.60).aspx) method on the `FormBuildGridControl`.

You can see an example in *\Classes\SysTableBrowser\showAllFields*